# How to add spaces to every two numbers with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, tostring

I like to output a formatted number with a space after every two numbers, I've tried this:

```
 function twoSpaceNumber(num) {
    return num.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d)(?=([0-9]{2})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
}
```

`twoSpaceNumber(12345678)` => `1 23 45 67 89` ( should start with 12 ? )

and also when it starts with 0 I had very strange output

`twoSpaceNumber(012345678)` => `12 34 56 78`

Comment: Pass `num` as a string, not a number, else the leading zeros will disappear and use `.replace(/\d{2}/g, '$& ')`

Comment: Does it matter if the characters are in the range "0" to "9", or do you just want to insert a space after every two characters?

Comment: Is the format you want to use some usual format in a particular culture? There migh tbe something already made for that.

Answer (score 2):

Pass `num` as a string, not a number, else the leading zeros will disappear and use

```
function twoSpaceNumber(num) {
  return num.replace(/\d{2}(?!$)/g, "$& ");
}
```

The regex matches two digits that are not at the end of string (in order not to add a space at the string end).

**JavaScript demo**

```js
const regex = /\d{2}(?!$)/g;
function twoSpaceNumber(num) {
  return num.replace(regex, "$& ");
}
const strings = ['123456789','012345678'];
for (const string of strings) {
  console.log(string, '=>', twoSpaceNumber(string));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider

```js
var s = "1234456";
var t = s.match(/.{1,2}/g);
var u = t.join(" ");
console.log(u);
```

which logs

> 12 34 45 6

and

```js
var s = "ABCDEF";
var t = s.match(/.{1,2}/g);
var u = t.join(" ");
console.log(u);
```

which logs

> AB CD EF

Note that `s` **is** a string.

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a non-regex approach:

```js
function twoSpaceNumber(num) { 
    var res = '';
    num += '';
    for(var i = 0; i < num.length; i+=2)
    {    
        res += num.substr(i,2) + ' ';
    }
    return res.trim();
}
```

Comment: Do remember that if you want a 0 at the front of the number, you need to pass it as a string otherwise javascript will ignore it